# Can we make a useful ring on an Elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

I know that given an elliptic curve $E$ we can define an addition $+$ over the set of points on the curve to make in an abelian group. However

**Can we define multiplication on $E$ in a natural way so that $E$ can be made into a ring?**

Edit:

**Can we do this in a non-trivial way?**

Comment: Not in a useful way, no. Depending on your precise setting (ground field), sometimes not at all.

Comment: This question is sufficiently vague as to have little content. First when you say $E$ is an elliptic curve and you want to make $E$ into a ring, you're presumably talking about the points of $E$. So you must specify a field. Second, if you simply want a ring "in a non-trivial way", the answer doesn't seem interesting. (Generally, if $G$ is an abstract abelian  group, can one put a non-trivial ring structure on it?) Maybe the right question is: Can we find an *algebraic* map $E\times E\to E$ that we'll call multiplication and that, with +, satisfies the ring axioms. The answer to that is no.

Comment: Joe -- take $G=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Since $G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}G=0$, there are no ring structures on $G$ at all.

Comment: .. apart from the zero one.